# Java implementation of FastDTW for gesture recognition

Tags: algorithm

I have an android application which is getting gesture coordinates (3 axis - x,y,z) from an external source. I need to compare them with coordinates which I have in my DB and determine whether gesture is the same/similar or not.

I also need to add some tolerance, since accelerometer (device which captures gestures) is very sensitive. It would be easy, but I also want to consider e.g. "big circle" drawn in the air, same as "small circle" drawn in the air. meaning that there would be different values, but structure of the graph would be the same, right?

I did some research and I found out I could use `Dynamic time wraping` possibly in combination with `Hidden Markov model`.

I tried to do some further reading on it, but I didn't find much. I just found a Java library called `FastDTW` but can't figure out which methods are the right ones for my problem.

Would you please provide me any lead on this?

See these images, they are the same gesture but one is done in a slower motion than another.

Faster one:
[image: Faster]

Slower one:
[image]

I haven't captured images of the same gesture where one would be smaller than another, might add that later.